# Why isn't my HTML aligning to center?

Tags: html, alignment, center

I'm sorry, I'll admit I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to HTML. But I can't see where I'm going wrong. I've declared the page to be **aligned center**, but for some reason invisible to me, it won't actually align!

My code is here...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: inherit;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 600px;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: central;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.Headertext2 {
}
h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
}

h6 {
    font-size: medium;
    color: #000;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
      </style>      <title>We'll fix your Potholes!</title>
    </head><center>
 <body bgcolor="#B90D32"> <div id="container" width "1200" align="center" >
<h1>A1Jay Pothole Solutions</h1>
<h3><strong>Permanent Pothole Repair that lasts</strong></h3>
<div id="content" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  width"600" class="content">
  <h6>Potholes are a growing problem and cause lasting damage to your vehicle. 
  We here at A1JAy Pothole Solution have the solution. We use only the best products on the market to repair potholes ensuring that the problem is fixed permanently and never returns. Our repairs are professional water tight and permanent. We replace any road markings that may be removed. We respond quickly to repair any holes, therefore stopping the damage to your vehicle.
    Our products are cold lay, fully graded to PSV-60 and all packaging is recyclable. 

    We have different rates depending on the amount of potholes you require permanently repairing, get in touch for details.

    If you have a pothole on your drive, street, place of work, car park, walkway or anywhere else, please get in contact and I will happily give you a free, no obligation quote..  </h6>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I apologise if this question has already been asked, I'm still getting to know Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Please put this into fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a stripped down (and working) solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WDTCK/1/

### Major Points

- `<center>` is obsolete* (it's also an illegal parent for `body`, and unclosed in your example)
- `align=center` is obsolete*
- A simple way to center something using CSS is to assign a container element a width and `margin: 0 auto`

Like this:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;    
}
```

### Minor Points

- Always prefer styles declared separate from the markup
- Always declare styles using CSS (not deprecated properties like `bgcolor="#B90D32"`)
- Make sure you are using headings correctly. I see H1, H3, and H6. Headings should represent the outline of your document; they should not be used just for formatting.

Here's a cleaner example which demonstrates better semantics: http://jsfiddle.net/WDTCK/2/

<sup>* ["obsolete and non-conforming, and [...] must not be used by authors."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete)</sup>

Comment: Wow, thanks... I really need to tidy this up. Thanks for that, and thanks also for showing me JSFiddle. Thumbs up for you!!

Comment: No problem. I added another example to help you out with the remaining markup. Also remember you can validate your code with [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: This does not work for this giphy: https://giphy.com/gifs/season-8-the-simpsons-8x21-l0G170YiUYqwSSgeI/embed unless I need to move all the inline css they provide to the same external CSS and change up somethings I'm lost.

Answer (score -2):

Put this inside the body

```
    <div align = "center">
    <!--somecodes-->
    </div>
```